# Overflow logo outside nav bar

Tags: html, css

[image: Sample of how the error looks]

[image: This is what i'm trying to accomplish]

I've tried the overflow-y: visible in css but the logo still cuts, i imagine it has something to do with the body since, in all the other pages the logo shows as i want it to.

```
 <div class="nav-logo">
 <img class="lightup-logo" src="image/logo.png" alt=""/>
</div>
    .nav-logo {
  float: left;
  overflow-y: visible;
  width: 24%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  }
```

On a side note the logo works as intended in all other pages, it overflows nicely, its just in the index page that the problem seems to appear.

For those who are looking for a complete code sample.

```
    <header>
    <div class="header-container">
      <div class="nav-logo">
         <img class="lightup-logo" src="image/logo.png" alt=""/>
        </div>
    </div>
    </header>
    <main>
    <div class="body-container">
    <div class="large-container"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    </main>



header {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background: rgba(31,34,36,1);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(31,34,36,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 25%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 77%, rgba(31,34,36,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(31,34,36,1)), color-stop(25%, rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(77%, rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(31,34,36,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(31,34,36,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 25%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 77%, rgba(31,34,36,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(31,34,36,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 25%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 77%, rgba(31,34,36,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(31,34,36,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 25%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 77%, rgba(31,34,36,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(31,34,36,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 25%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 77%, rgba(31,34,36,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1f2224', endColorstr='#1f2224', GradientType=1 );   
}
.nav-logo {
      float: left;
      overflow-y: visible;
      width: 230px;
      height: 100%;
      width: 24%;
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
  }
.header-container {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    border-left: 0px;
    border-right: 0px;
    border-top: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    -webkit-border-image: url(/border.png) 28 stretch; /* Safari 3.1-5 */
    -o-border-image: url(/border.png) 28 stretch; /* Opera 11-12.1 */
    border-image: url(/border.png) 28 stretch;

}
main {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
 .large-container {
      height: 478px;
      background-image: url(../image/sliced1.png);
  }
.body-container {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
    position: relative;
}
```

If i add z-index: -1 to the body-container i get the result i want (logo overflows) however links in the body-containers no longer work.

Comment: Most probably, the image (or one of its parents) has a higher `z-index` than the logo (or one of its parents). Please provide a [mcve] of your problem and I will pinpoint/fix it for you.

Comment: I've changed the z-index a few times the only one that seems to work (which still poses a problem is z-index: -1;) i'm sure thats not my answer since it leaves the div and all of its child divs frozen unable to click any links within that particular negative z-index link div.

I'm probably doing it wrong.. i'll try to update this post with more complete and useful code to illustrate my problem.

Comment: You are dealing with a stacking context issue. Unfortunately, it's not the `z-index` of the logo you have to change but of the parent where the stacking context is created. Please pay more attention to my previous comment. [mcve] should mean: *recreate the problem* so we experience it. Where can I experience your problem?

Comment: you can find the live version of the site at [link](http://holapex.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `screen_styles.css`, `line 48`, remove `z-index: 5px;`. `z-index` has nothing to do with pixels.
- add these rules to *header* `line 14`:

```css
header {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

That's about it. The reason why `z-index` did not work was because you were trying to use it on a `position:static` element. It only works on elements with `position` other than `static`.

Your project has quite a few errors, you should have a decent front end developer look at it before you launch, to put it mildly.

Comment: Thank you for the help, and yes i understand there are mistakes/errors all over the place.. i'm honestly very new to this, but practice makes perfect and like the Chinese proverb says "he who asks a question is fool for five minutes, but he who does not ask remains a fool forever." 

I'm sure i don't need to tell you that what you suggested worked.

Again thank you, for taking the time.

Comment: Also, thanks for the advice about the fonts.. they should be fixed now.. i did not notice that since my browser showed the website with proper fonts.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.nav-logo img 
  {
    max-width: 100px; //width of div
    max-height: 100px;//height of div
  }
```

or you can make logo.png, background of div

```
<div class="nav-logo">
</div>
```

and use

```
.nav-logo {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background-image: url("image/logo.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
}
```

contain makes background image fill the div and not getting bigger.